# C# - How to get a CPU Temp / CPU Load / Current Voltage / VID Voltage / Current Frequency with LibreHardwareMonitor?

Tags: c#, cpu, openhardwaremonitor

For my C# .Net Framework project I need to get 5 values:

1. CPU Load
2. CPU Temp
3. Current Voltage
4. VID Voltage
5. Current Frequency

I tried WMI, but it doesn't work with modern CPUs, and can't get those values correctly.
After doing some research, I figured that the best way to obtain those values would be to use OpenHardwareMonitor or LibreHardwareMonitor ([Git](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor)).

So, I installed LibreHardwareMonitor NuGet, it's added all references and the sample code from GitHub compiles, but the console closes immediately.

From the sample code below, you can tell that it outputs every single metric that it can obtain, while I need just those 5 values that I mentioned above.

If anyone has experience with LibreHardwareMonitor or OpenHardwareMonitor, I would truly appreciate it if you would tell me how to get just those values that I need.

```
public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
{
    public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
    {
        computer.Traverse(this);
    }
    public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
    {
        hardware.Update();
        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
    }
    public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
    public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
}

public void Monitor()
{
    Computer computer = new Computer
    {
        IsCpuEnabled = true,
        IsGpuEnabled = true,
        IsMemoryEnabled = true,
        IsMotherboardEnabled = true,
        IsControllerEnabled = true,
        IsNetworkEnabled = true,
        IsStorageEnabled = true
    };

    computer.Open();
    computer.Accept(new UpdateVisitor());

    foreach (IHardware hardware in computer.Hardware)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hardware: {0}", hardware.Name);
        
        foreach (IHardware subhardware in hardware.SubHardware)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tSubhardware: {0}", subhardware.Name);
            
            foreach (ISensor sensor in subhardware.Sensors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value);
            }
        }

        foreach (ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value);
        }
    }
    
    computer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use OpenHardwareMonitor with this code. Then extract cpuUsage, cpuTemp, etc., from ReportSystemInfo();

```
using System;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace PPSU_hwmonitor_c
{
    class Program
    {
        /**
         *  Define vars to hold stats
         **/

        // CPU Temp
        static float cpuTemp;
        // CPU Usage
        static float cpuUsage;
        // CPU Power Draw (Package)
        static float cpuPowerDrawPackage;
        // CPU Frequency
        static float cpuFrequency;
        // GPU Temperature
        static float gpuTemp;
        // GPU Usage
        static float gpuUsage;
        // GPU Core Frequency
        static float gpuCoreFrequency;
        // GPU Memory Frequency
        static float gpuMemoryFrequency;

        /**
         * Init OpenHardwareMonitor.dll Computer Object
         **/

        static Computer c = new Computer()
        {
            GPUEnabled = true,
            CPUEnabled = true,
            //RAMEnabled = true, // uncomment for RAM reports
            //MainboardEnabled = true, // uncomment for Motherboard reports
            //FanControllerEnabled = true, // uncomment for FAN Reports
            //HDDEnabled = true, // uncomment for HDD Report
        };

        /**
         * Pulls data from OHM
         **/

        static void ReportSystemInfo()
        {
            foreach (var hardware in c.Hardware)
            {

                if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                {
                    // only fire the update when found
                    hardware.Update();

                    // loop through the data
                    foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature && sensor.Name.Contains("CPU Package"))
                        {
                            // store
                            cpuTemp = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cpuTemp: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());

                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load && sensor.Name.Contains("CPU Total"))
                        {
                            // store
                            cpuUsage = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cpuUsage: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());

                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Power && sensor.Name.Contains("CPU Package"))
                        {
                            // store
                            cpuPowerDrawPackage = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CPU Power Draw - Package: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());


                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Clock && sensor.Name.Contains("CPU Core #1"))
                        {
                            // store
                            cpuFrequency = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("cpuFrequency: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());
                        }
                }


                // Targets AMD & Nvidia GPUS
                if (hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuAti || hardware.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
                {
                    // only fire the update when found
                    hardware.Update();

                    // loop through the data
                    foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature && sensor.Name.Contains("GPU Core"))
                        {
                            // store
                            gpuTemp = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("gpuTemp: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());
                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Load && sensor.Name.Contains("GPU Core"))
                        {
                            // store
                            gpuUsage = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("gpuUsage: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());
                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Clock && sensor.Name.Contains("GPU Core"))
                        {
                            // store
                            gpuCoreFrequency = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("gpuCoreFrequency: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());
                        }
                        else if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Clock && sensor.Name.Contains("GPU Memory"))
                        {
                            // store
                            gpuMemoryFrequency = sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
                            // print to console
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("gpuMemoryFrequency: " + sensor.Value.GetValueOrDefault());
                        }

                }

                // ... you can access any other system information you want here

            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            c.Open();

            // loop
            while (true)
            {
                ReportSystemInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```